# Как сделать так, чтобы на стикер от пользователя бот отправил айди стикера

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при отправлении стикера бот отправил тебе его айди.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте обработчик по типу контента `sticker`. Идентификатор стикера будет возвращён в виде `message.skicker.file_id`. Вот пример:

```
import telebot

TOKEN = 'ваш токен'

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Обработчик для стикеров
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(message):
    sticker_id = message.sticker.file_id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ID этого стикера: {sticker_id}")

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]